# Not completely logout using "www.gigya.com"

Tags: javascript

I am trying to integrate Gigya(www.gigya.com) javascript api for social network login . I am successfully login with facebook. Also when I click on logout button  it seems that i get logout from facebook. But when I again click on facebook login button then it not asking for login id and password, directly get login from my account. 
The code is use is as follows:

gigya.services.socialize.logout(conf, {});

I have searched on gigya's forum and i found that it only logout from gigya's platform but not from the facebook.

Can any one know, how to get out from this problem? Please help..

Comment: 8 questions, none accepted so far. Please, give me at least a good reason why should we help you?

Answer (score 0):

they have maintain their cookies and session that's why you can not logout from all for example stackoverflow if you used openId then you know that. when you login using openid for e.g. google account id then open gmail you directly view your inbox and if you logout from the gmail/stackoverflow then only one of them will logout because they have maintain individual cookies and session for login time they for openid they create cookies related to that service provider like google or anyelse

Comment: ok..so is there any way to get login from social site with my website? I can't use openid concept because i want to access login person's image and its email id.

Answer (score 0):

for this to happen we need to set the flag forceProvidersLogout  to true in the params that we sent to gigya.
Refer to the api  link @ http://developers.gigya.com/020_Client_API/020_Methods/socialize.logout